# How to disable a program in "Startup Applications" via command line

Tags: command-line, autostart, startup-applications

I know how to do this via GUI, but now I need to do this via CLI.

I cannot delete, for example, `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop` file from `/etc/xdg/autostart`, because my system (Ubuntu 18.04) stops booting.

[booting problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4wJj.png)

I need to uncheck (or remove) item in the startup programs list.

[GIF, which explains what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZIAV.gif)

Comment: Don't give us `gif`s take the time to put it down in writing!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen open your eyes! I have already described my problem in the text. GIF is optional here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the file into `~/.config/autostart/` and then edit that new file, changing the `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` value from `true` to `false`.